# Xamarin.Forms: Rendering Xamarin.Froms Control in native Dialog - wrap_content ignored

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Say I want to render a Xamarin.Froms control (e.g a `Xamarin.Forms.Label`) in a native android view.
The following code works. But ignores the width and height of the control (`wrap_content`).

```
// create a Xamarin.Froms.Label
Xamarin.Forms.Label view = new Xamarin.Forms.Label()
{
    Text = "This is a Xamarin.Forms.Label",
    BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
};

// create a Renderer
var renderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer(view);

// create an AlertDialog
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);
builder.SetView(renderer.ViewGroup); // Use the ViewGroup of the renderer
builder.SetTitle("Dialog");
// create and show the dialog
builder.Create().Show();
```

Produces the following:

[image: Xamarin.Forms.Label screenshot]

Doing the same with an native label:

```
var view = new Android.Widget.TextView(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context)
{
    Text = "This is a Android.Widget.TextView",
    Background = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Red),
};
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);

builder.SetView(view);
builder.SetTitle("Dialog");
builder.Create().Show();
```

Produces the expected output:

[image: Android.Widget.TextView screenshot]

I am looking for any hints or advices regarding width / height measurement in Xamarin.Forms, and/or a solution for this kind of problem.

---

### Update

Also note that this does not depend on the `AlertDialog`, using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `AlertDialog` results to the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> The following code works. But ignores the width and height of the control (wrap_content).

**Reason:**

You passed a `ViewGroup` to the `AlertDialog`. But inside the `AlertDialog` the layout params of `ViewGroup` won't work at all. Refering to [this blog](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/):

> **Every Rule Has An Exception**
>
> ...
>
> The issue here is that AlertDialog.Builder supports a custom view, but does not provide an implementation of setView() that takes a layout resource; so you must inflate the XML manually. However, because the result will go into the dialog, which does not expose its root view (in fact, it doesn’t exist yet), we do not have access to the eventual parent of the layout, so we cannot use it for inflation. It turns out, this is irrelevant, because **AlertDialog will erase any LayoutParams on the layout anyway and replace them with match_parent**.

So instead of passing a `ViewGroup`, pass a view to `AlertDialog` like your second try.

**Update(a few more research):**

if try the following codes to set the height of `ViewGroup` to 400:

```
// create a Renderer
var renderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer(view);
// create an AlertDialog
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);
renderer.ViewGroup.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 400);
builder.SetView(renderer.ViewGroup); // Use the ViewGroup of the renderer
builder.SetTitle("Dialog");
// create and show the dialog
builder.Create().Show();
```

It doesn't work, the dialog is still almost covers the whole screen:

[image]

But if add the renderered `ViewGroup` to `LinearLayout` like this:

```
var renderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer(view);
//The following codes works correctly
renderer.ViewGroup.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 400);
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);
linearLayout.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
linearLayout.AddView(renderer.ViewGroup);
this.AddContentView(linearLayout,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
```

The height was set correctly:

[image]

So, **on this layer, the problem lies in the `AlertDialog` as I mentioned above.**

But If the height was set to `Wrap_content` like this:

```
var renderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer(view);
//set the height again to wrap_content
renderer.ViewGroup.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
linearLayout.AddView(renderer.ViewGroup);
this.AddContentView(linearLayout,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
```

the rendererd `ViewGroup` again start to fill the whole screen:

[image]

**On this layer I found that the problem lies in the rendered `ViewGroup`**, because after changing the `ViewGroup` to a native `LinearLayout` everything is fine.

I checked the Source codes of Xamarin.Forms, and found the following Inherit hierarchy:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.AndroidLabelRenderer ->
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer<TView, TNativeView> ->
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer<TElement> ->
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup ->
Android.Views.ViewGroup
```

**I found none of these classes has implemented `ViewGroup.OnMeasure` method.** Thus the `wrap_content` will never work. You can refer to [Custom ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) for an detailed implementation example of custom `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I think this is not the reason: 1. Rebuilding the example with a LinearLayout instead of a AlertDialog results to the same misbehaviour. 2. Wrapping the native TextView in an ViewGroup results in a correct behaviour

Comment: @Eun I don't know how you tested, But I had a few digging on my own, please check my update.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question since It is probalby the easiest way to solve the problem:

Since Xamarin.Forms 2.3.5 (as time of writing in prerelease) there is a new Property `View` next to `ViewGroup` in `IVisualElementRenderer`.

The solution would be to use Xamarin.Froms 2.5.3 and the property `View`:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Label view = new Xamarin.Forms.Label()
{
    Text = "This is a Xamarin.Forms.Label",
    BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
};

var renderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer(view);
var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);
builder.SetView(renderer.View); // Use View instead of ViewGroup
builder.SetTitle("Dialog");
builder.Create().Show();
```